# TeX accents on XeLaTeX without fontspec

Tags: bibtex, fontspec, font-encodings

I'm trying to use XeLaTeX with BibTeX8 without fontspec, but I'm getting my bibliography wrongly accented as with the files.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Aristoteles2000mf,
  Title                    = {Metaf{\'i}sica},
  Author                   = {Arist{\'o}teles},
  Publisher                = {Gredos},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Address                  = {Madrid},
  Note                     = {Trad. Tom{\'a}s Calvo Mart{\'i}nez},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The wrong output, with accents on dotted i's, is [image: no dotlessi]

Is there a kludge to fix the output withouth going into reencoding all my old bib files?

Comment: You shouldn't do `\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}` to begin with. The encoding is chosen automatically when `fontspec` is used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. And you shouldn't use BibTeX8 when XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is concerned.

Comment: the idea is to avoid fontspec. so let me restate my question...

Comment: It makes very little sense to use XeLaTeX without `fontspec`.

Comment: So why not use `{\'\i}`?

Comment: @Werner: partly, historical reasons (good old pdfLaTeX+babel used to take care of that); but you're right, perhaps I should fix all those strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands like your `\'i` are provided by xunicode (which is normally loaded by fontspec). You can load it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\UTFencname{EU1}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\begin{document}
Metaf{\'i}sica,
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What `filecontents` package? I didn't use it.

Comment: I didn't use it either...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't use BibTeX8 with UTF-8 files.

I see no reason for doing acrobatics with `fontenc` and `xunicode`. Let's run your file, assuming the `.bbl` file has not yet been created, so no error happens.

We get some warnings from LaTeX:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/cmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 23.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/cmr/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 27.
```

to which another one would be added if the `.bbl` is loaded:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/cmr/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.
```

(line numbers may not agree). What does it mean? Very easy: the `EU1` encoding establishes a font substitution

```
\DeclareErrorFont{EU1}{lmr}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{EU1}{lmr}{m}{n}
```

so LaTeX will use the `lmr` family. However, this is the *only* substitution rule, so you'll get no boldface, italic, small caps, sans serif and whatnot.

If you plant the line `\expandafter\show\the\font` in the file, just after `\begin{document}`, compilation will stop with the message

```
> \EU1/lmr/m/n/10=select font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text".
<inserted text> \EU1/lmr/m/n/10 

l.25 \expandafter\show\the\font
```

Now, change `\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}` into `\usepackage{fontspec}`. You'll have no warning and compilation will stop with

```
> \EU1/lmr/m/n/10=select font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text".
<inserted text> \EU1/lmr/m/n/10 

l.25 \expandafter\show\the\font
```

and no other font warning.

The moral is that loading `fontspec` does exactly the same thing as you want, without any trick. Since `fontspec` automatically loads `xunicode`, there's no problem in translating `\'i` into `í` at runtime.

Comment: I know the drawbacks, and I see your points; but mine is to avoid loading the experimental BloaTeX3 code, required by fontspec. Besides, with a carefully crafted eu1lmr.fd file (like the one already included with euenc), or others homebrewed for different sets of fonts, most or all of these warnings disappear. The main thing is: fontspec does its own tricks and acrobatics, but require a whole subsystem to work, and I'm not quite ready to follow them.

Comment: @LiTzu I think your worries are out of place. I use quite extensively `expl3`, alone or because of `fontspec` and `unicode-math` and have no problem, except some “youth defects” that are always cured in a short interval of time. Anyway, you're the customer, so you're right by definition. `;-)`

Comment: Having said that, I'd like to know what is the problem with using bibtex8 with XeTeX. UTF8 strings are 8 bit, right?

Comment: @LiTzu UTF-8 strings are multibyte.

Comment: But still, they may be digested by BibTeX8. The only drawback I foresee is trouble in sorting, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there...